# R - gt package - Ability to control cell padding within table header and column labels?

Tags: r, gt

**Problem**
The *gt* package allows for a few cell padding parameters to be passed within *tab_options()*. For example, *data_row.padding* and *footnotes.padding*. However, there are no parameters available which affect the *table header* or *column labels* parts of the gt Table.

**Question**
Is there any way to control the cell padding within the *table header* or *column labels* parts of the gt Table?

**Reproducible example with massive cell padding for demonstration:**

```
gt_tbl <- gt(data = mtcars) %>% 
  tab_header(
     title = "mtcars dataset") %>% 
  tab_options(data_row.padding = px(35))

gt_tbl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are arguments within `tab_options()` for handling padding of the requested elements.

```
gt(data = mtcars) %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = "mtcars dataset") %>% 
  tab_options(data_row.padding = px(35), 
              column_labels.padding = px(35), 
              heading.padding = px(35))
```