# R gt table gt data.row.padding for certain columns only

Tags: r, padding, gt

I came across this question and basically I want to do the same thing, but set the cell padding only for certain columns.

[R - gt package - Ability to control cell padding within table header and column labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679314/r-gt-package-ability-to-control-cell-padding-within-table-header-and-column)

This is my dataframe:

```
gt(data = mtcars) %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = "mtcars dataset") %>% 
  tab_options(data_row.padding = px(10), 
              column_labels.padding = px(3), 
              heading.padding = px(5), 
              data_row.padding.horizontal = px(5))
```

And I want to apply the "`data_row.padding.horizontal`" only to the last 4 columns for example. In my real case I have a vector full of column numbers, where I want to reduce the data_row.padding to 0. My desired output would be a data_row.padding for the whole table of 10, but in the last 4 columns I want padding 0. The helper function "locations" is not working for me and I dont really know how to work with a loop in this case.

Comment: If you add that code, does it work?
 ` tab_style(
    style = list(
      css(
        props = "padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;"
      )
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c("vs":"carb")
    )
  )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you could use is setting the column width conditionally. I've included 2 examples of how to do this.

- In the first, I've just assigned this width to the column `vs`.
- In the second, I've modified `mtcars` so that all columns are not numeric, then assigned the width to numeric columns. Lastly, I centered no numeric columns so the padding variation would be more obvious

Here are two examples of setting the column width conditionally.

Just the `vs` column:

```
gt(data = mtcars) %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = "mtcars dataset") %>% 
  cols_width(vs ~ pct(10))
```

[image]

All columns that are `numeric`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl),
         across(vs:carb, factor)) %>%          # change some fields to factor
  gt() %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = "mtcars dataset") %>% 
  cols_width(where(is.numeric) ~ pct(15)) %>%  # widths of numeric columns
  cols_align(align = c("center"),              # center non-numeric
             columns = where(is.factor))
```

[image]